# Can I conditionally use the Copy function in ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Our solution is deployed to multiple environments, Dev, Test and Prod. I conditionally deploy Virtual Networks and other beefy network infrastructure for non-dev environments. The struggle I'm having is with applying Access Restrictions to the web config of an App Service, only when a boolean is true (using copyIndex).

The below works for assigning the subnet access restrictions to the App Service:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "ukwest"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "networkingRequired": true,
    "aspName": "xxxMyAppServicePlan",
    "siteName": "xxxMySite1",
    "vnetName": "superVnetName",
    "subnetNames": [
      "subnetone",
      "subnettwo",
      "subnetthree"
    ]
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[variables('aspName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "kind": "app",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {},
      "sku": {
        "name": "S1",
        "capacity": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "app",
      "name": "[variables('siteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('aspName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
          "httpsOnly": true,
          "alwaysOn": true,
          "virtualApplications": [
            {
              "virtualPath": "/",
              "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
              "preloadEnabled": true
            }
          ],
          "copy": [
            {
              "name": "ipSecurityRestrictions",
              "count": "[length(variables('subnetNames'))]",
              "input": {
                "vnetSubnetResourceId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('vnetName'), variables('subnetNames')[copyIndex('ipSecurityRestrictions')])]",
                "action": "Allow",
                "priority": "1",
                "name": "[variables('subnetNames')[copyIndex('ipSecurityRestrictions')]]",
                "description": "[concat(variables('subnetNames')[copyIndex('ipSecurityRestrictions')], ' subnet')]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('aspName')]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So what I now need to do is have it respect the variable 'networkingRequired' and only do the "copy" for ipSecurityRestrictions when networking is true.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837119/15740725) for a different approach using a filtered array with lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

easiest way of doing this - move the copy to the variables section and use an expression to define the value of `ipSecurityRestrictions` "on the fly".

```
"variables": {
    "empty": [],
    "copy": [you copy goes here]
},
...
"ipSecurityRestrictions": "[if(variables('networkingRequired'), variables('ipSecurityRestrictions'), variables('empty'))]"
```

Comment: Amazing! I tried this based on your response to another similar post, but the Intellisense of ARM Tools in VS Code didn't recognise `variables('ipSecurityRestrictions')` as a variable so I never went ahead with attempting to deploy it! Thank you

Comment: yeah, intellisense for ARM Templates is garbage =\ consider accepting this if it answers your question ;)

Comment: well, its certainly better than nothing, but confusing if you dont know what you are doing exactly and it tells you that this wouldn't work. you just have to not trust it except for it detecting obvious errors\typos