# Conditional Copy in Azure ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to create an SQL failover group. For that, I need to pass an array of databases that is build based on the parameters. I want to filter the list of DBs coming from params based on a certain field:

Params:

```
"databases": {
      "value": [
        {
          "name": "db1",
          "replicated": true
        }, 
        {
          "name": "db2",
          "replicated": false
        }, 
...
]}
```

Now I want to create a variable and filter this list based on the "replicated" field.

```
copy": [
  {
    "name": "dbResourceIds",
    "count": "[length(parameters('databases'))]",
    "input": "<some filtering magic here>"
  }
]
```

Does ARM support that?

Comment: What do you want the filtering magic to do?  Or what's the end result you're after in the array?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @bmoore-msft I wanted to have an array containing objects where "replicated == true". Looks like ARM does not support that kind of filtering and instead condition should be used on the copy loop of the resource.

Comment: So based on replicated==true you want to deploy a resource (and if not true, don't deploy it)?  The only way you could do that would be to nest the deployment of the resource and put the condition in the nested deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition option is a property of the resource, it can't exist in the copy block. So if you create multiple resources with a copy, then you can use the condition in the resource property. But if you want to use the copy in the properties of a resource, then you can't set the condition. See the copy for the [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-properties#property-iteration).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda expression create a new variable that is filtered off the `databases` param, and then base your copy off that. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-lambda#filter).

In your case you can do:

```
"filteredDatabases": "[filter(parameters('databases'), 
    lambda('db', lambdaVariables('db').replicated))]",
"copy": [
  {
    "name": "dbResourceIds",
    "count": "[length(variables('filteredDatabases'))]",
    "input": "<whatever data points you want>"
  }
]
```

Note ARM Tools extension in VS Code doesn't recognize lambda for some reason.